# Populate multiple spinner dynamically from json response using retrofit

Tags: android, json, spinner, android-spinner

I'm trying to populate multiple `spinner`s from `JSON` response using `retrofit`.

In `JSON` response I'm fetching all the details. I'm populating spinner1.

How do I populate the rest of the spinners on the basis of the first `spinner` selection.

Spinner1, Spinner2, Spinner3.
On selection of item in Spinner1, Spinner2 should be populated.
On selection of item in Spinner2, Spinner3 should be populated.

```
 ExpertSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {

          }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        }
    });



@Override
public void onSuccess(Response response, GlobalVariables.SERVICE_MODE mode) {
    switch (mode) {
        case AGRI_EXPERTS:
            try {
                List<CC_AgriExpertModel> expert = (List<CC_AgriExpertModel>) response.body();
                ArrayList<String> productList = new ArrayList<>();

                for (int i = 0; i < expert.size(); i++)
                {
                    productList.add(expert.get(i).getExpert_name());

                }
                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1;
                adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, productList);

                //setting adapter to spinner
                ExpertSpinner.setAdapter(adapter1);
                adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;
           }
}
```

Comment: set OnItemSelected Listener to each spinner  then spinner1 onItemSelected set adpater for spinner2..do same for all simple

Comment: thanks Munir, Can you post some examples